# Haskell Lens Tutorial with traverse

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://blog.jakubarnold.cz/2014/08/06/lens-tutorial-stab-traversal-part-2.html

I'm using the following code that I load into ghci:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables  #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Traversable

-- Define Lens type.
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t 
type Lens' s a = Lens s s a a 

-- Lens view function. Omitting other functions for brevity.
view :: Lens s t a b -> s -> a
view ln x = getConst $ ln Const x

-- Tutorial sample data types
data User = User String [Post] deriving Show
data Post = Post String deriving Show

-- Tutorial sample data
john = User "John" $ map (Post) ["abc","def","xyz"]
albert = User "Albert" $ map (Post) ["ghi","jkl","mno"]
users = [john, albert]

-- A lens
posts :: Lens' User [Post]
posts fn (User n ps) = fmap (\newPosts -> User n newPosts) $ fn ps
```

From there, simple stuff like this works:

```
view posts john
```

However, when I try to do the next step it does not work:

```
view (traverse.posts) users
```

I get:

```
Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of ‘traverse’
from the context (Functor f)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             Functor f => ([Post] -> f [Post]) -> [User] -> f [User]
  at <interactive>:58:1-27
Possible fix:
  add (Applicative f) to the context of
    a type expected by the context:
      Functor f => ([Post] -> f [Post]) -> [User] -> f [User]
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘traverse’
In the first argument of ‘view’, namely ‘(traverse . posts)’
In the expression: view (traverse . posts) users
```

I see that Lens has a type constraint of Functor and traverse has a more constrained type constraint on f as an Applicative. Why exactly isn't this working and why did the blog tutorial suggest that it works?

Comment: If you delete your definitions of `Lens`, `Lens'`, and `view` and instead import them from `Control.Lens`, it works, though that still leaves the question of why yours aren’t working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view` actually has a type that's less restrictive than `Lens s t a b -> s -> a`.

If you drop the type signature, ghci will tell you the type for `view`

```
:t view
view :: ((a1 -> Const a1 b1) -> t -> Const a b) -> t -> a
```

This is less restrictive because a `Lens` must be defined `forall` functors, while the first argument to view only needs to be defined for `Const a1`.

If we rename the type variables based on the names from `Lens` and restrict `a1 ~ a` this signature will make more sense

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f =>
         (a -> f       b) -> s -> f       t 
view :: ((a -> Const a b) -> s -> Const a t) -> s -> a
view ln x = getConst $ ln Const x
```